# How to install rlocate in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: kernel, search, find, locate

rlocate is an implementation of the locate command that is always up-to-date.

I installed the deb package from [official site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rlocate/) . It was installed successfully, but but it fails to load kernel module. After searching a bit, what I understood is that, there is some problem with the kernel module.

Is there any way to make it run in 16.04? Is there any fork of rlocate which is compatible with 16.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have migrated it under [deepin](https://www.deepin.org/) .

It should be workable under ubuntu 16.04. (kernel after 4.0)
The source code is under https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-rlocate

deepin 15.4 would pre-installed rlocate as its file-manager's search backend plugin.

Comment: the primary change is in https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-rlocate/commit/292013a16394a400e96d815e5f9a99b54b5f7c45

You can build the deb by `debuild -uc -us`